# What package would allow for the creation of a certain type of chart?

Tags: packages, mindmaps

I don't know the formal name for the chart shown below. However, it is there a package that would allow one to create this?

[image]

Comment: ...how odd; I created that mind map. :)

Comment: ...it's a small world. Did you use LaTeX? I found it in a text I use for reference for Graph Theory.

Comment: Yes, I was the editor for that entire graph theory text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of graphic is referred to as a mind map. You can find some [examples on how to create these on TeXample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/):

[image]

It uses the `mindmap` [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgf) library.